# Force printing of SOAPHeader contents with SOAPMessage.writeTo

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, wsimport

I'm a little perplexed as to the observed behaviour of SOAPMessage#writeTo - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPMessage.html#writeTo-java.io.OutputStream-

I've built a SOAPHandler to ensure all my outgoing SOAP messages have some specific SOAP Headers set on them. I have the following code which grabs the output that's going to be sent:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
message.writeTo(out);
String strMsg = new String(out.toByteArray());
```

If I pipe the above to stdout, I see a message like so:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><S:Body xmlns:ns2="http://blah.com/blah" xmlns:ns3="http://foo.com/foo"><ns2:myStuff>...</ns2:myStuff></S:Body></S:Envelope>
```

Which indicates empty headers... yet if I interrogate the header objects programatically I can see content is there:

```
System.out.println(message.getSOAPHeader().getElementsByTagName("ns:MyHeader"));
System.out.println(message.getSOAPHeader().getElementsByTagName("ns:MyHeader").getLength());
System.out.println(message.getSOAPHeader().getElementsByTagName("ns:MyHeader").item(0).getFirstChild());
System.out.println(message.getSOAPHeader().getElementsByTagName("ns:MyHeader").item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent());
```

which prints:

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl@d2a3aad
1
[my:Id: null]
111111
```

From reading the doco I know MIME headers won't be printed, but I would have thought SOAPHeaders would have no problem?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @4535992 unfortunately we did not